# Pass kind parameter to subprogram

Tags: fortran, precision

Is it possible in modern versions of Fortran to pass a kind parameter to a subprogram and to use this to 'cast' variables to this kind? As an example, in the following code I am trying to convert an default integer to an 16-bit integer before printing it.

```
program mwe

! Could use iso_fortran_env definition of int16, but I am stuck with
! old versions of ifort and gfortran.
! use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : int16

implicit none

! 16-bit (short) integer kind.
integer, parameter :: int16 = selected_int_kind(15)

call convert_print(123, int16)

contains

  subroutine convert_print(i, ikind)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: i
    integer, intent(in) :: ikind

    print*, int(i, ikind)

  end subroutine convert_print

end program mwe
```

With this example code the Intel Fortran compiler complains that

> mwe.f(24): error #6238: An integer constant expression is required in this context.   [IKIND]
>   ...
>   mwe.f(24): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant   [IKIND]

and gfortran complains

> 'kind' argument of 'int' intrinsic at (1) must be a constant

Using `print*, int(i, int16)` in place of `print*, int(i, ikind)` would of course work fine in this case. However, if `convert_print` were defined in a a module which does not define `int16` then this would be useless.

Is there a way of passing a kind parameter as a constant to subprograms?

Comment: What stops you from putting the constant in a module and using it where required?

Comment: @IanH I could, but then I would need a separate subprogram for each kind, which I came to realise after posting this question (see my answer). I was hoping there was a way to write a single subprogram which takes a kind parameter as an argument. However, it seems that this is not possible and that I have the wrong data model for Fortran in mind (kinds are basically different types, and types can't be passed around, i.e. you can't pass integer to a function) - I have obviously spent too much time working with higher level languages where you can pass types around.

Comment: Are you writing a library?  For the data that you are dealing with, is the same data represented in different kind integers in the same program?  Typical use case is to have a program wide "Kinds" module that describes the kinds to use for each class of data in the program.  If you are writing library support procedures and need to instantiate a template of a procedures for a range of kinds then typical use is to put the generic body of the procedure in a separate file, and use INCLUDE to pull that body into actual specific procedure definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can work out, what I am trying to do is expressly forbidden by the Fortran 2003 standard ([PDF, 4.5 MB](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/04/04-007.pdf)):

> #### 5.1.2.10  PARAMETER attribute
>
> A named constant shall not be referenced unless it has been defined previously in the same statement, defined in a prior statement, or made accessible by use or host association.

Therefore is seems that I need to define a function for each conversion I wish to do, for example:

```
subroutine print_byte(i)
  implicit none
  integer, intent(in) :: i

  print*, int(i, int8)

end subroutine print_byte

subroutine print_short(i)
  implicit none
  integer, intent(in) :: i

  print*, int(i, int16)

end subroutine print_short

subroutine print_long(i)
  implicit none
  integer, intent(in) :: i

  print*, int(i, int32)

end subroutine print_long
```

Obviously all of the above will have to be overloaded to accept different kinds of the input argument. This seems like a lot of work to get around not being able to pass a constant, so if someone has a better solution I am keen to see it.

Comment: You can use include or PyF95++ templates. Not as a workaround, but as a way how to shorten the work you show above.

Comment: `includes` will definitely help, although there will still be a lot of similar code. Never heard of PyF95++ but it looks interesting - thanks for the tip.

Comment: Why do you go to all the trouble of defining subroutines for the different integer kinds and then use compiler-specified default output formatting ?  Or is this just a simplification of what you really want to do ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark This is a simplification of what I want to do. In my minimal example I am just printing an integer, but in a real program I am trying to print information about the numeric data model, so I need to apply inquiry functions etc to an integer of the kind `ikind`.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem. I find extremely inconvenient that it is not allowed to pass the kind datatype as an argument to a procedures. In my case, I am writing write a subroutine to just read a matrix from a file and get the object in the data type that I want to. I had to write four different subroutines: ReadMatrix_int8(…), ReadMatrix_int16(…), ReadMatrix_int32(…) and ReadMatrix_int64(…) which are nothing but the same code with one single line different:

```
integer(kind=xxxx), allocatable, intent(out) :: matrix(:,:)
```

It would make sense to write only one subroutine and pass xxxx as an argument. If I find any solution I will let you know. But I am afraid that there is no better solution than writing the four subroutines and then writing an interface to create a generic procedure like:

```
interface ReadMatrix
     module procedure ReadMatrix_int8
     module procedure ReadMatrix_int16
     module procedure ReadMatrix_int32
     module procedure ReadMatrix_int64
end interface
```

Answer (score 2):

This Intel expert gives an explanation and an elegant solution. I couldn't explain it better. [A full cite follows](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2006/10/05/domestic-or-imported):

"One day while I was wandering the aisles of my local grocery store, a woman beckoned me over to a table and asked if I would like to "try some imported chocolate?" Neatly arrayed on the table were packages of Lindt, Toblerone, and... Ghiradelli? I asked the woman if California had seceded from the Union, as Ghiradelli, despite its Italian name, hails from San Francisco. I suppose that from the vantage point of New Hampshire, California might as well be another country, much as depicted in that famous Saul Steinberg 1976 cover for The New Yorker, "View of the World from 9th Avenue".

(I've been warned that my blogs don't have enough arbitrary links - this should hold 'em for a while.)

Similarly, in Fortran (I'll bet you were wondering when I'd get to that), something can be so near yet seem so far away. A short time ago, I was writing a new module for Intel Visual Fortran to provide declarations for the Win32 Process Status API. This would contain declarations of types and constants as well as interface blocks for the API routines, some of which take arguments of the new type. The natural inclination is to write something like this:

```
MODULE psapi
TYPE sometype
some component
END TYPE sometype

INTERFACE
FUNCTION newroutine (arg)
INTEGER :: newroutine
TYPE (sometype) :: arg
END FUNCTION newroutine
END INTERFACE

END MODULE psapi
```

If you did and compiled it, you'd get an error that type sometype is undefined in the declaration of arg. "What? It's not undeclared, I can see it right above in the same module!" Well, yes and no. Yes, it's declared in the module and could be used anywhere in the module, except.. Except in interface blocks!

The problem is that interface blocks are a "window into the external routine" - they essentially duplicate the declarations you would see in the actual external routine, assuming that routine were written in Fortran. As such, they do not "host associate" any symbols from the enclosing scoping unit (the module in this case.)

In Fortran 90 and Fortran 95, the typical solution for this was to create a separate module, say, "psapi_types", containing all of the types and constants to be used, You'd then add a USE statement inside each function, just as you would have to in the hypothetical external routine written in Fortran. (If it were written in Fortran, the Doctor would slap your wrist with a wet punchcard and tell you to make the routine a module procedure, and then you wouldn't need to worry about this nonsense.) So you would end up with something like this:

```
MODULE psapi
USE psapi_types ! This is for the benefit of users of module psapi
INTERFACE
FUNCTION newroutine (arg)
USE psapi_types
INTEGER :: newroutine
TYPE (sometype) :: arg
...
```

Those of you who use Intel Visual Fortran know that in fact there's a giant module IFWINTY for this purpose, containing all of the types and constants for the other Win32 APIs. It's messy and inelegant, but that's what you have to do. Until now...

Fortran 2003 attempts to restore some elegance to this sorry situation, but to preserve compatibility with older sources, it couldn't just declare that interface blocks participate in host association. Instead, a new statement was created, IMPORT. IMPORT is allowed to appear in interface blocks only and it tells the compiler to import names visible in the host scope.

IMPORT is placed following any USE statements but before any IMPLICIT statements in an interface body (the FUNCTION or SUBROUTINE declaration). IMPORT can have an optional import-name-list, much like USE. Without one, all entities accessible in the host become visible inside the interface body. With a list, only the named entities are visible.

With IMPORT, my PSAPI module can look like the first example with the following change:

```
...
FUNCTION newroutine (arg)
IMPORT
INTEGER :: newroutine
TYPE(sometype) :: arg
...
```

I could, if I wanted to, use:

```
IMPORT :: sometype
```

to say that I wanted only that one name imported. Nice and neat and all in one module!

"But why are you telling me this?", you might ask, "That's a Fortran 2003 feature and Intel Fortran doesn't yet do all of Fortran 2003." True enough, but we keep adding more and more F2003 features to the compiler and IMPORT made it in back in August! So if you are keeping reasonbly current, you can now IMPORT to your heart's content and do away with the mess of a separate module for your types and constants.

If you want to know what other F2003 goodies are available to you, just check the Release Notes for each update. A full list of supported F2003 features is in each issue. Collect 'em all!"

Comment: You could have at least fixed the formatting after the copy and paste and shorten it. But actually I do not see any connection with the question.

Comment: As far as i understand you're passing a custom type of variable. When you use kind, you define a custom lenght of real variable. It's the same case when you make the statement `TYPE (sometype) :: arg` in Fortran with `integer (kind=xxxx)`.